# Populating Drop-down Value using dynamic identifiers from Multiple Select tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I was working to grab the drop down selected value dynamically using dynamic identifiers. I have done it in static way. Can anybody suggest how can I make 'id' dynamic for each 'button' and 'select' tags and On click of each GO button the value should be displaying from the same row's select drop down. Thanks in advance.

```
=================

$(".button").click(function() {               
              var dataItem = $(this).data('item'),
              contentID = $('#'+dataItem);
              $('#output').html(contentID.val())
          });


=============

<table cellspacing="10" cellpading="10" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Application Name</td>
            <td>
                <select id="country">
                    <option>Select Any Country</option>
                    <option value="India">India</option>
                    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                    <option value="England">England</option>
                    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="button" data-item="country" class="button" value="Go" /></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Application Name</td>
            <td>
                <select id="country1">
                    <option>Select Any Country</option>
                    <option>China</option>
                    <option>Russia</option>
                    <option>France</option>
                    <option>Paris</option>
                    <option>Germany</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="button" data-item="country1" class="button" value="Go" /></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Application Name</td>
            <td>
                <select id="country2">
                    <option>Select Any Country</option>
                    <option>Sri Lanka</option>
                    <option>South Africa</option>
                    <option>Ireland</option>
                    <option>Spain</option>
                    <option>Serbia</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="button" data-item="country2" class="button" value="Go" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="output" style="color:red"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign dynamic "id" for select and button

```
  var n =1;
   $("table tr input.button").each(function(n){
      $(this).attr("id" , "button"+n);
      $(this).parent().find("select").attr("id" , "country"+n);
   });
```

Now on click

```
  var y =1;
  $("table tr input.button").each(function(y){
      $("#button"+y).live('click', function(){
         alert($("#country"+y+" option:selected").index());
       });
   });
```

Comment: I think instead of setting **id** of the button, it would be better to set the **data-item** and **id** of select tag same as the **data-item** value of the button.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what u expecting ...try this

```
$("table tr td").each(function(n){
     var id = $(this).find("select").attr("id");
     if(id)
        $("#output").append($("#"+id+" :selected").val()+"<br>");
   });
}
```

check with fiddle:**http://jsfiddle.net/tamilmani/QrbWy/**